# Expression Engine list category entry only

Tags: expressionengine

With the code below, I am currently showing all the categories for the channel, but I only need to show the category or categories for each entry.  They have been checkboxed in each seperate entry.

What am I missing?

```
  {exp:channel:entries channel="news" dynamic="no" orderby="date" sort="desc" }

<article class="listing">

        <h2><a href="#">{title}</a></h2>
    <p>Posted on: {entry_date format="%F %j, %Y"} in {exp:channel:categories channel="news" style="linear" show_empty="no"}
        {category_name},{/exp:channel:categories}</p> 

            <p class="summary">{news_summary}</p>

    <p style="margin-top: 10px;"><a href='{url_title_path='news/view'}'>Read More</a></p>

      </article>
```

{/exp:channel:entries}

Comment: Headsup that there is an ExpressionEngine specific StackExchange site now: http://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

Problem was, I was using regular channel type tags for categories.  The correct code for this is....

```
  {exp:channel:entries channel="news" dynamic="no" orderby="date" sort="desc" }

<article class="listing">

        <h2><a href="#">{title}</a></h2>
    <p>Posted on: {entry_date format="%F %j, %Y"} in 

    {categories  backspace="1"}
             {category_name},
    {/categories}</p>

            <p class="summary">{news_summary}</p>

    <p style="margin-top: 10px;"><a href='{url_title_path='news/view'}'>Read More</a></p>

      </article>
```

{/exp:channel:entries}